# Remove Dates from a GoCentral Blog

Tags: css, css-selectors

My client is using GoCentral from GoDaddy for his website and has included a blog section. We'd like to remove the date shown in the blog.

The blog lives in a DIV with an ID of:
`aa247afb-8241-4560-a96e-a6755b95ea2d`.

The date lives in a `<p>` tag with the following attributes:

```
data-ux="Text" data-aid="RSS_FEED_POST_DATE_RENDERED"
```

Comment: @MartinZeitler: I don't have access to the CSS files with GoCentral. But I am able to inject Javascript using their custom HTML sections.

Comment: the CSS selector which I provided below also works with jQuery https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ or with vanilla JS `document.querySelectorAll()`.